# そういうの and そういうこと

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances, usage, word-usage

1. ‎When you use そういうの you are talking about "things/living things" but also about "topics", more abstract subjects right? like, doing some sports, or talking about "this"

そういうのは興味ない

- I don't have interest in this (in politics)
- I don't have interest in this (in toys)

そういうのはない

- there isn't such a thing (it's not true)
- there isn't such a thing (something doesn't exist) ?...

But would you そういうこと with an object?

そういうことは嫌だ

- I don't like this kind of thing (maybe a girl that doesn't like insects)

or should I use そういうのは嫌だ instead?

2. When you use そういうこと at the of a sentence, it "usually" means that the others person's conclusion is about right and you are agreeing with them. Can I use そういうの is this same context?

はい、そういうことです

- Yeah, you're right